# Oracle Apex - How to change color of a calendar entry depending on the current date?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I created a reservation calendar in Apex where I write down reservations for the week and every reservation type has its own color. Now I want to make sure that when a reservation end date passed the current date that the calendar entry changes color to grey.

This is my SQL query:

```
select ID_REZ,
   POCETAK_REZ,
   KRAJ_REZ,/* This is the end date!*/
   NASLOV_REZ,
   case when NASLOV_REZ is not null then
      title || '(' || BR_OSOBA_REZ || ' x ' || NAZIV_USLUGE || ' na ' || BR_SATI_REZ ||  ' sata. Detalji:  ' || NASLOV_REZ || ' )' || '[Šifra rezervacije: '|| ID_REZ ||']'
   end as title,
   BR_OSOBA_REZ,
   BR_SATI_REZ,
   case
    when USLUGA_FK = 13    then  'apex-cal-red'
    when USLUGA_FK = 14 then  'apex-cal-orange'
    when USLUGA_FK = 15  then  'apex-cal-blue'
    when USLUGA_FK = 16 then 'apex-cal-green'
    when USLUGA_FK = 17 then 'apex-cal-lime'
    when KRAJ_REZ < CURRENT_DATE then 'apex-cal-grey'
end as CSS_REZ /* This is where i store my colors for each entry*/
  from REZERVACIJE
  JOIN USLUGA ON USLUGA_FK = ID_USLUGA
  where 
(nvl(:VRSTA_USLUGE,'0') = '0' or USLUGA_FK = :VRSTA_USLUGE)
order by POCETAK_REZ
```

This kinda doesn't work so I'm open to any suggestions!

PS: My theory is that unfortunately, this last `when` statement is overlapping with at least 1 more color change so the first color that passes the `WHEN` statement "wins" the place in the CSS_REZ column.

But my brain doesn't work now on how to fix it please help!

Comment: try moving the grey when statement to the top or use else when instead of only 'when'

Comment: Moving the grey statement to the top actually solved the problem, and it completely makes sense! thank you !!!